# compiled Python code complains lack of Python at deployed host

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I have Python script that I used cython to convert to C and then compiled
as binary (dynamic linking)

When I copy the binary to a different machine (I compiled on a MAC and also trying
to run on another MAC), I got this following error below.  Should I be setting
`PYTHONHOME` or `PYTHONPATH`?   The binary ran fine on the original machine without any special env variable.

-- ERROR ---

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000000011179c5c0 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Do you have Python installed on the other machine? Cython executables still depend on the Python standard library (and any other libraries you use) being installed normally - they are not self-contained

Comment: The destination machine does have python installed and working.   The binary was compiled by gcc with  "-lpython3.6m".   The destination machine also has that exact version.   The when I do "otool -L" on the binary, it is referencing /opt/lib/.../libpython3.6m.   That's the path on the original machine where python shared lib is installed.   It is still looking at this place in the destination machine?

Comment: It's looking for the Python standard library (the modules that you can import that are provided with Python). These are mostly .py files but I don't immediately know where they are. I think it's found the libpython .so file.